# Regex extract placeholder value, default exclusive

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have two types of input string:

```
${place.holder}
${place.holder:defValue}
```

I need to extract **only** `place.holder` whether it has a `:defValue` or not, i.e. desired result in both cases should be:

```
place.holder
place.holder
```

This is the full match: https://regex101.com/r/hjWEO1/1/
I've tried negative lookahead, but it matches omly first symbol in group.

Comment: Add `?` after a group that must be optional. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjWEO1/2). A `\${([^{}:]*(?::[^{}]*)?)}` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hjWEO1/3) might be a bit better here, but that is not relevant for the current problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question: I don't need `:defValue` to be included too

Comment: Then use `(\$\{)(.*?)(?:\:.*)?(\})` or `\${([^{}:]*)(?::[^{}]*)?}`